# How to disable and re-enable the 'click' and its function in the tags function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I write the code as the follows in `jquery` to make the content of the selected `.fly li`  appear in the tag_handler when I click the `.fly li`, it works.

My question is how can I disable click to the tag after click for once and re-enable after delete the tag in the tag_handler. Thanks.

```
function add_tag(that){
  var singleValues = $(that).html();
  $("#tag_handler").append(singleValues);
}

$(".fly li").click(function(){
    add_tag(this);
});
```

Comment: this is jquery? If so please mention it in your question.

Comment: Does `singleValues` contains `.fly` and `li` that you are appending??

Comment: No, the singleValues is a newly defined variable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BgkBU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a tiny demo which maybe meets your two requirements
js:

```
$(function(){
    var tags = [];
    function add_tag(that){
      var tag = $(that).text();
      if($.inArray(tag, tags)>=0) return;
      tags.push(tag);
      var singleValues = $(that).html();
      $("#tag_handler").append(singleValues);
    }

    $(".fly li").click(function(){
        add_tag(this);

    });

    $('#tag_handler').on('click', 'span', function(){
        var tag = $(this).text();
        var index = $.inArray(tag, tags);
    tags.splice(index,1);
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<ul class="fly">
    <li><span>Tag 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Tag 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Tag 3</span></li>
    <li><span>Tag 4</span></li>
</ul>
Tags:
<div id="tag_handler"></div>
```

1. Click ".fly li" to add tag into "tag_handler"; if it's already tagged, do nothing.
2. Click the tag in "tag_handler" to delete, then you can add again;

Comment: `pop` removes the last element of array, isn't it?

Comment: That works great！ Thanks， but could I ask one more question? How can I limit the number of the tags in the tag_handler? On the conditions that the other functions work also. Thanks.

Comment: That's easy. Add your max number of tags in:
if($.inArray(tag, tags)>=0 || tags.length >= [MAX]) return;

Comment: You mean under 'tags.splice(index,1);
        $(this).remove();'? I add it, but it seems doesn't work. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I find it! Misunderstood before... Thanks again！